# angular - cannot make sortablejs work due to runtime error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sortablejs, angular-sortablejs

I'm trying to use this lib: https://github.com/SortableJS/ngx-sortablejs

I've installed by: `npm i ngx-sortablejs sortablejs --save`

My page HTML

```
<div [sortablejs]="items">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Then I'm importing in my `app/app.module.ts`

```
import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs';

...

SortablejsModule.forRoot({ animation: 150 })
```

And for the last, import module in my `page.module.ts`

```
import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs';       <<==== HERE

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SortablejsModule,                                <<==== AND HERE
 ...
```

So the app is compiling with no error but when I try to open the page with component, i get this runtime error:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: OriginalSortable.create is not a function
TypeError: OriginalSortable.create is not a function
    at sortablejs.directive.js:32
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at NgZone.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:17258)
    at SortablejsDirective.push../node_modules/angular-sortablejs/dist/src/sortablejs.directive.js.SortablejsDirective.ngOnInit (sortablejs.directive.js:31)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22099)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the error `OriginalSortable.create is not a function` appeared after upgrading to Angular 8.

By upgrading `ngx-sortablejs` to 3.1.3 and `sortablejs` to 1.10.1, the error went away.